# Synonym request [hangout] -> [google-plus-hangouts]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, tag-synonyms

Please make [hangout](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hangout) a synonym of [google-plus-hangouts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-plus-hangouts).

Comment: I'm accustomed to say google hangout rather than a google plus hangout. Is that a technicality? Should it be plural?

Comment: Those are just the tags as they currently exist. Whether those are the correct names and/or should be pluralized is a different discussion. Most of the other G+ features get a "google-plus-" prefix on them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been done. I have merged the tags and created a synonym.